# How do I resolve certification path error using STRING app in Cytoscape?

Tags: java, cytoscape

I am a new Cytoscape user and just installed the application on my Windows 10 machine, updating Java 8 and installing Java 11 per tutorial instructions. Cytoscape opens fine and I installed the STRING app. When I try to search using the STRING disease query a dialog box opens with the following error:

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How do I correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there.  If you run Cytoscape from the command line, do you see a stack trace?  That will help us figure out what's going on.  For some reason, your machine isn't recognizing a certificate from either STRING or the Jensen Lab.  You could also try just going to https://string-db.org and https://jensenlab.org and see if your browser gives any errors.